# "Track Changes" disappeared

Tags: visual-studio

I just used my Visual Studio for writing code on C++ and faced to problem. Change tracker vertical line(on a left side of the VS window) disappeared. Besides in any of my projects.
I tried reset "Track changes" box and restart VS and whole Windows system and that had no affect.
[image: screenshot]

Is anyone know what happens?

Comment: Did you by chance reload your project?  If so, Visual Studio will end up clearing those trackers  out.  This happens a lot if say you pull from a remote branch that has been modified and Visual Studio needs to reload the project.

Comment: @TimothyG. what means "reload my project"? overload it a lot of code? or do something like "rebuild it"?

Comment: By reload project, I mean if you ever seen this prompt and then clicked "Reload" or "Reload All": https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHyR3.png This prompt will appear if say you pulled down new code that modifies the project file for your project (.csproj file for a C# project for example).  Also, if you [unloaded a project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHLxI.png) and then reloaded it.